# ros_control loops with different frequency

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Is it possible to specify loops with different frequencies in ros_control?

More specifically I am thinking about a low-level loop for motor control (I am thinking something like 200 1000Hz) and a somehow higher level loop for differential or mecanum drive control (something between 30Hz and 100Hz)?

These loops can both use ros_control but the higher the level, the slower the requirements for the speed of the loop...

Thanks,

Antoine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192953/ros_control-loops-with-different-frequency/) by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [Controllers at different update rates in ros_control](http://answers.ros.org/question/113266/controllers-at-different-update-rates-in-ros_control/), which contains a reference to [ros_control/pull/127](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/pull/127): "Added optional per-controller update period".

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) on 2014-09-22**:
The referenced pull request is indeed what you should be looking at. I believe the implementation is there, but is lacking test coverage. Adding this missing bit would fast track the merging process, otherwise it might sit there until someone has the cycles to pull it through.

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-09-24**:
Hi guys, thanks for your help, I'll have a look at these.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-09-24**:
Question answered?

**Comment by [arennuit](https://answers.ros.org/users/3981/arennuit/) on 2014-09-24**:
and marked as such ;)